# Prisma ORM Dont Show Option of CREATE in my Model/Table React JS

Tags: reactjs, orm, prisma

how are you? I need your help, I can't figure out why my 'const newPlace = await prisma.place.create({}) doesn't have a "create" option for my model below:

I have other tables that work, the create option appears, I need to know why only this 'place' model does not have the create option?

my 'schema.prisma' below

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets   = "native"
  previewFeatures = ["extendedIndexes", "improvedQueryRaw"]
} 

model place {
  id                          Int                      @id(map: "place_pk") @default(autoincrement())
  place_id                    String                   @db.VarChar
  name                        String                   @db.VarChar(255)
  nationalPhoneNumber         String?                  @db.VarChar(20)
  internationalPhoneNumber    String?                  @db.VarChar(20)
  formattedAddress            String?                  @db.VarChar(255)
  plusCode_globalCode         String?                  @db.VarChar(20)
  plusCode_compoundCode       String?                  @db.VarChar(255)
  latitude                    Float?
  longitude                   Float?
  rating                      Float?
  pricelevel                  Float?                    @db.Real
  googleMapsUri               String?                   @db.VarChar(255)
  websiteUri                  String?                   @db.VarChar(255)
  instagram                   String?                   @db.VarChar(255) @unique
  utcOffsetMinutes            Int?
  adrFormatAddress            String?                   @db.VarChar(1000)
  businessStatus              String?                   @db.VarChar(20)
  userRatingCount             Int?
  iconMaskBaseUri             String?                   @db.VarChar(255)
  iconBackgroundColor         String?                   @db.VarChar(20)
  displayName                 String?                   @db.VarChar(255)
  primaryTypeDisplayName      String?                   @db.VarChar(255)
  takeout                     Boolean?
  delivery                    Boolean?
  dineIn                      Boolean?
  reservable                  Boolean?
  servesBeer                  Boolean?
  liveMusic                   Boolean?
  servesCocktails             Boolean?
  restroom                    Boolean?
  goodForGroups               Boolean?
  goodForWatchingSports       Boolean?
  acceptsCreditCards          Boolean?
  acceptsDebitCards           Boolean?
  acceptsCashOnly             Boolean?
  acceptsNfc                  Boolean?
  
  route                       String?                   @db.VarChar
  street_number               String?                   @db.VarChar
  sublocality_level_1         String?                   @db.VarChar
  administrative_area_level_1 String?                   @db.VarChar
  administrative_area_level_2 String?                   @db.VarChar
  postal_code                 String?                   @db.VarChar
  country                     String?                   @db.VarChar
  events                      event[]
  favorite                    favorite_place[]
  location                    Unsupported("geography(Point, 4326)")
  photos                      place_photo[]
  active                      Boolean @default(true)
  instagram_business          instagram_business?

  @@unique([place_id], map: "place_un")
  @@index([id])
  @@index([location], name: "location_idx", type: Gist)
}
```

Comment: `npx prisma generate`

Comment: hi @MahmoudElshazly tks for your comment, but I rum npx prisma generate, but dont solve my problem, I have anothers model that have a option “create” but only model “place” above dont have de function create in prisma.place.’<create>’ where can I see files generate for i see the option created?

Comment: It works normally for me
if you in **dev mode** try `npx prisma migrate reset`
be careful All data will be lost

Answer (score 1):

Solved: as I am using PostGis from Postgres, my field `location Unsupported("geography(Point, 4326)")` is causing the `create` function to disappear.

Solution: included location as optional with '?' at the end, as follows:
location `Unsupported("geography(Point, 4326)")?`